# Is it possible to change multiple propeties of newly created object without creating reference?

Tags: c#, instance

I want to know if there is a way to write for example:

```
Thread th = new Thread(smth);
th.IsBackground = true;
th.Start();
```

In one line(with more properties too)?

```
new Thread(smth).{IsBackground = true, Start()} ;
```

Comment: Note that "one-line" is not a sign of quality

Comment: @TimSchmelter Usually quite the opposite when it comes to readability, maintainability, sanity...

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it, you can do:

```
var thread = new Thread(smth)
{
    IsBackground = true
};
```

No need for the `.`. They're known as *Object Initializers*, you can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).

You can't do this with methods of course you'd still have to call `Start()` outside of this.

Comment: is new Thread(smth){
                IsBackground = true,
            }.Start(); good?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this:

```
new Thread(smth){IsBackground = true}.Start();
```

Comment: If they wanted to keep a reference to the thread object, that wouldn't work. Otherwise, it would, sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialize properties in one line. You have to call method in another line.

```
Thread th = new Thread(smth){ IsBackground = true;};
th.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ObjectInitializer` assign Properties not anything else.
You must call Start method outside of Initializer Block.

```
var th= new Thread(smth)
{
    IsBackground = true
};
th.Start();
```

or

```
new Thread(smth)
{
    IsBackground = true
}.Start();
```